# Echo <script src= from server via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

If I do this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'http://server.com/script.php',
    type: 'POST',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: complete_data,
    complete: function(response, textStatus) {
        if (textStatus === 'success') {
            jQuery('#content > form').html(response.responseText);
        }
    }
});
```

And then script.php on server.com looks like this:

My work's firewall doesn't let me post this with a script tag in it, but imagine a php ecript echoing out a javascript script tag to the URL https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places

Then I get this error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://my-local-machine.dev' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Where do I set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in order to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You set it in the HTTP headers of `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places`, which you can't since you (presumably) aren't Google.

The attempt to fetch the script via XHR instead of a script element is probably due to the way jQuery tries to handle adding HTML with script elements in it via `.html()`. Build your DOM using `createElement`/`appendChild`/etc instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: Unfortunately I have inherited this project from another developer, and the way that script.php works is it just echos out html, so I can't really use appendChild or createElement. I can easily put the script tag on the same server as the javascript files are on, but it would be nice to do it from the server running script.php. Is there any other way?